# Android: Get json from URL - nullPointerException

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

I try to load `Json` from `URL`. By not using  `AsyncTask` class on previous version, It worked well.
 However call `getJSONFromUrl(currentURL)` directly from main `Thread` (someone told me) is not accepted in 3.2 or higher Android versons.
   So, I tried by the following code.
this is my code:

```
private static String urlTruyenMoiNhat = "myUrl";
private static String currentURL = urlTruyenMoiNhat;
private static JSONObject jSonGetFromCurrentURL = null;

//some stuff....
currentURL = urlTruyenMoiNhat;
GetJsonAsync getJson = new GetJsonAsync();
getJson.execute();
RetreiveListStory(jSonGetFromCurrentURL);
```

This is my GetJsonAsync  class:

```
private class GetJsonAsync extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Do stuff before the operation
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        jSonGetFromCurrentURL = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(currentURL);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Do stuff after the operation
    }
}
```

I don't know why it through exception:

```
11-28 13:30:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(828): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 13:30:44.084: E/AndroidRuntime(828): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{vn.truyencuoihay/vn.truyencuoihay.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please help me overcome this problem.
  Thanks!

Comment: Please 1) post the full exception stack trace, including the "caused by" parts, if any; 2) read that stack trace and find out which line in your code it points to; 3) mark that line in the code you posted (e.g. by a comment)

Comment: Post your full stack trace so we can know that at which line it throws null pointer exceptions???

Comment: NullPointerException is in the line RetreiveListStory(jSonGetFromCurrentURL);. My problem is solved by moving the line RetreiveListStory(jSonGetFromCurrentURL); into onPostExecute();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually happens in AsyncTask is when u call execute.. it starts a separate thread..  and all your other commands are excuted in Oncreate() without waiting for the result (in your case jSonGetFromCurrentURL)form AsyncTask ..
so u get null pointer exception..

write this line in **onPostExecute();**

```
RetreiveListStory(jSonGetFromCurrentURL);
```

FYI
 AsyncTask

actually means

```
AsyncTask <String input, Void progress, String result>
```

Comment: NullPointerException is in the line RetreiveListStory(jSonGetFromCurrentURL);. My problem is solved by moving the line RetreiveListStory(jSonGetFromCurrentURL); into onPostExecute(); Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

why are u returning null at this line-
jSonGetFromCurrentURL = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(currentURL);
        return null;

return jSonGetFromCurrentURL.instead of null.